# Can't get data to load into jTable in mvc 4

Tags: jquery, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, json, jquery-jtable

Okay, so I'm trying out jTable for the first time and I can get the table to load, but that does me very little good because it won't load with any of my data. When I debug the program, all of the rows from the table I want are getting stored in my List so I'm confused as to why a dialog box pops up when I run my application saying 'An error occured while communicating to the server':

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult General_InfoList(int jtStartIndex = 0, int jtPageSize = 0, string jtSorting = null)
{
    try
    {
        // When debugging, all rows are successfully being stored in this list
        // but a dialog box pops up saying 'An error occured while communicating to the server.'
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        var genInfoCount = _repository.General_Info_Repository.GetGeneral_InfoCount();
        var genInfo = _repository.General_Info_Repository.GetGeneral_Info(jtStartIndex, jtPageSize, jtSorting);
        return Json(new { Result = "OK", Records = genInfo, TotalRecordCount = genInfoCount });

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
     }
}
```

And in my view I have:

```
<div id="General_InfoTableContainer">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#General_InfoTableContainer').jtable({
            title: 'General_Info List',
            paging: true,
            pageSize: 10,
            sorting: true,
            defaultSorting: 'Quote ID ASC',
            actions: {
                listAction: '@Url.Action("General_InfoList")',
                deleteAction: '@Url.Action("DeleteGeneral_Info")',
                updateAction: '@Url.Action("UpdateGeneral_Info")',
                createAction: '@Url.Action("CreateGeneral_Info")'
            },
            fields: {
                QuoteID: {
                    key: true,
                    create: false,
                    edit: false,
                    list: true,
                    title: 'ID',
                    width: '5%'
                },
                Open_Quote: {
                    title: 'Open Quote',
                    list: true,
                    width: '15%',
                    type: 'date',
                    displayFormat: 'mm-dd-yy'
                },
                Customer_Name: {
                    list: true,
                    title: 'Customer',
                    width: '25%'
                },
                OEM_Name: {
                    title: 'OEM',
                    list: true,
                    width: '25%'
                },
                Qty: {
                    title: 'Qty',
                    list: true,
                    width: '5%'
                },
                FD_Num: {
                    title: 'FD Num',
                    width: '10%',
                    list: true,
                    sorting: false
                },
                Rfq_Num: {
                    title: 'RFQ',
                    width: '10%',
                    list: true,
                    sorting: false
                },
                Rev_Num: {
                    title: 'Rev',
                    width: '5%',
                    list: true,
                    sorting: false
                },

                Score_Card: {
                    create: false,
                    edit: false,
                    list: false
                },
                Quantities: {
                    create: false,
                    edit: false,
                    list: false
                },
                QuoteAccesses: {
                    create: false,
                    edit: false,
                    list: false
                },
                Vendor_Input: {
                    create: false,
                    edit: false,
                    list: false
                }              
            }
        });

        //Load student list from server
        $('#General_InfoTableContainer').jtable('load');
    });

</script>
```

If anyone sees anything in my code above that would prevent the data from loading please let me know. --Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are missing `JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet` from your `return Json(...)` statement. It seems that it's optional, but I find in reality it's required.

```
return Json(new { Result = "OK", Records = genInfo }, JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
```

Bonus Hint: when you get mysterious 500's from your ajax calls, do the following inside Visual Studio:

1. Debug menu->Exceptions...
2. Select 'Common Language Runtime Exceptions'.

This will force your server code to stop when/if an exception occurs.  Of course, it can also show you false positives, so you may want to be selective on when you turn this on.

Comment: Hey Matt, thanks for the input. I made that change and I'm still not getting any data in my table. Is there something wrong in the way I've set up my view that I'm missing?

Comment: Assuming your data is returning successfully (use your browser's debug tools to verify), it may be that you're returning the records in a `Records` property, where your jTable may not be expecting that.  It may be expecting your column properties to be in the root of your json data.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying here (a product of my inexperience with this). How can I get the Records property to return my data if `{ Result = "OK", Records = genInfo }` isn't the way to do it?

Comment: Try returning your `genInfo` results directly instead of wrapping it in another structure.

Comment: If I understand correctly (and again I appologize for my inexperience with this), I tried returning genInfo right in Results ( so: `Results = genInfo ` ) and that also did not work. Is it definitely there in the controller that my issue is? Or is there some other area that's preventing my table from connecting to the database?

Comment: According to the docs (http://www.jtable.org/GettingStarted?ref=homebuttons), using `return Json(new { Result = "OK", Records = genInfo }, JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);` should return the records correctly from the controller.  Have you confirmed you received valid records in json form using your browser's debugging tools?

Comment: Hey Matt, sorry for being absent for a couple of days. So, when I debug in Visual Studio, genInfo is properly storing a list containing all of my data, so it appears that my controller is working properly (although I could be wrong). However, when I debug inside the browser, I get one error: `SCRIPT5022 Caught Exception : syntaxError` and the error is being flagged at line 17, character 2266 in jquery.min.js. Because this is obviously not an error showing up in a file I created, I'm wondering what could be causing that. Im looking up the error now, but is anything sticking out at you? -Thanks

Comment: I'm a noob on jtable but have experience with other languages.  Sometimes the error is flagged on the wrong line, it's really elsewhere.  You generally have 4 options in that case.  1) Eliminate & Isolate.  Eliminate anything non-essential to recreating the problem.  That will help you isolate.  If you eliminate something and it starts working - you've come closer to isolating the problem.  2) Scan the code visually looking for something missing such as a quote or semi-colon for example.  3) Step through the code one line at a time with a debugger.  4)use print statements instead of stepping.