# Empty error message with jQuery.jTable

Tags: json, jquery-ui, nancy, jquery-jtable

I'm having problems with the [jquery.jtable.js](http://jtable.org/) plugin.

**My problem:**

jTable continues to post this empty modal error message:

[image: jTable error message on load]

For your information:

- I'm using [NancyFX](http://nancyfx.org/) for my backend.
- There are no 404s, everything is 200 OK
- The objects I'm returning are plain POCOs, no proxies or anything of that nature

This is my HTML:

```
<!-- in the header -->
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Scripts/jtable/themes/basic/jtable_basic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jtable/external/json2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jtable/jquery.jtable.min.js"></script>

<!-- in body -->
<div id="UsersTableContainer"></div>
```

I have this javascript (whithin a $(document).ready()):

```
$('#UsersTableContainer').jtable({
    title: 'All users',
    paging: true,
    pageSize: 10,
    sorting: true,
    defaultSorting: 'UserName ASC',
    actions: {
        listAction: '/api/backend/users/list',
    },
    fields: {
        UserName: {
            title: 'UserName',
            key: true,
            list: true,
            width: '20%',
            sorting: true
        }/* and more 
            I've tried userName and UserName - nothing works
            I've tried to map all properties and none, using a test column - nothing works */
    }
 });
 $('#UsersTableContainer').jtable('load');
```

I can see with fiddler 2 that this is sent across the line:

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "userName": "user"
      /*, more properties */
    }/*, more records */
  ],
  "result": "OK",
  "message": "All OK", //tried with an without this, just to see if it pups up
  "totalRecordCount": 2
}
```

Similar questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21360730/c-sharp-asp-net-jquery-jtable
- [Can't get data to load into jTable in mvc 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740808/cant-get-data-to-load-into-jtable-in-mvc-4)

Comment: How is this related to jquery ui?

Comment: jquery-jtable is dependant on jquery-ui, that's the reason I included it as a tag. For all I know it could be some configuration I need to do to jquery-ui to stop it from posting that message and potentially stop it stopping an event from propagating.

Comment: first link is broken

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same problem and found out, that in my case, I had changed the result from OK to SUCCESS and jTable was checking for OK.  Upon further investigation I also found out that jTable is expecting the result property to be capitalized (i.e. Result).  I didn't check, but I would guess that Records needs to be capitalized as does TotalRecordCount and Message.  I hope this tidbit will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to solve in this way (this is listAction property of jTable plugin):

```
listAction: function (postData, jtParams) {
    console.log("Loading from custom function...");
    return $.Deferred(function ($dfd) {
        $.ajax({
                url: '/api/backend/users/list',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {},
                success: function (data) {
                    data.Records = data.records;
                    data.Result = data.result;
                    data.TotalRecordCount = data.totalRecordCount
                    delete data.result;
                    delete data.records;
                    delete data.totalRecordCount;
                    $dfd.resolve(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    $dfd.reject();
                }
            });
        });
    },
},
```